# Java - read data from COBOL copybook

Tags: java, cobol, copybook

I have below `copybook`:

```
  10 TESTTYPES.
    30 NINETEEN PIC 9(2).
```

and my input in a `types.txt` file:

```
19
```

I am using [`cb2java 5.3`](https://github.com/devstopfix/cb2java) to convert the input to Java.

Below is my code:

```
List<Record> records = copybook.parseData(new FileInputStream(new File("types.txt")));
Record record = records.get(0);
GroupData data = (GroupData) record.getChild("TESTTYPES");
assertEquals(BigInteger.valueOf(19), data.getChild("NINETEEN"));
```

When I run this code, I expected `19` to be read. but it is reading `09` not `19` from my input file:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<19> but was:<09>
```

Am I missing or misunderstand anything?

Comment: There is no **19** in the input. Also, what is **copyBook** ?!

Comment: Why should this test pass? Please explain.

Comment: This has to do with sign position, forcing "leading" (see interface `Settings`), gives you the expected value.

Comment: @rc the data is defined as unsigned, so I don't see how any sign-position would affect the result positively.

Comment: I have to agree with @SamTebbs33. NINETEEN does not contain data which matches BigInteger.valueOf(19). So what is your *source* data and *source* copybook and what is in types.txt?

Comment: types.txt has value 19 which is my source data.

Comment: @BillWoodger Download the source of the lib (on [github](https://github.com/devstopfix/cb2java)), add a test case for the "TWELVE" case (`testWeCanParseIntegers`) and debug it, NB: I did

Comment: @Sridhar I edited your question to clarify (I hope) the input/copybook part, please correct the edit if I misunderstood

Comment: @RC. You mean the default is to expect a separate sign? Makes sense for a signed field, but if that's what you've found for an unsigned field, then yes, that may get to the explanation. A two-digit separate-signed field is three bytes long. If the `1` has been consumed as the sign, shouldn't there be a right-most "something" or some other indication that the length is still two? If you can get that included, why not post it all as an answer?

Comment: @BillWoodger My opinion is that there's a bug in the library, it makes no sense that (in the `testWeCanParseIntegers`) that it can "map" correctly the 3 "9" but not a "99" following them. And I don't understand why the lib is trying to parse some sign for a 99 field (without a S it's unsigned if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Guess the library is halfway cooked and it is last updated on 3 years back.

Comment: @Sridhar perhaps https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/, it has active and current support, and Bruce even attends here at times.

Comment: However, from your previous question, I had assumed you would chop up the fixed-length data into appropriate-length "strings" and just convert those to numbers in whatever manner you have intrinsically in Java.

Comment: let me try `jrecord`

Comment: `jrecord` worked !! :-) Able to parse decimals too!!